# My Google Sheets formulas mysteriously break as time passes, fix themselves when refreshed

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has one 'master sheet' set up to pull in data using formulas that reference a variety of 'feeder sheets'.  The feeder sheets are a landing spot for data that comes from a BI dashboard via scheduled exports every hour. I have never had any issued with the data populating in the feeder sheets correctly (so in my mind, this is not a dashboard issue.) On the master sheet, all of the formulas that I set up to pull in data from the feeder sheets basically work correctly, but they break from time to time.

For example -
Today I went into the sheet and noticed that many of my formulas were returning nulls. I checked the relevant feeder sheet and confirmed that the data is still there as expected. I then manually refreshed one of the cells (changed the formula, pressed enter, changed the formula back, pressed enter) and it immediately fixed the issue. Then I happened to notice that while I was in the sheet at exactly 1:30, the next batch of scheduled exports ran triggering the feeder sheets to refresh, and all the remaining broken cells immediately fixed themselves.

basically my takeaway is the following:

1. There's no problem with the BI dashboard export / feeder sheets, as far as I know the data is populating correctly 100% of the time.
2. There's nothing INHERENTLY wrong with the formulas. Sometimes they break, but I can always fix them by refreshing the cell. Also, it's not the same cells/formulas that break; seems to happen "randomly" to different cells each time.
3. It seems like some sort of issue with Google Sheets cacheing? This is the part where I am stumped, obviously.

Bonus point: I'm not 100% sure yet, but it seems like the troublesome formulas use min/max and explicit sheet references, for example "=MAX('SheetName'!A:A)" . I have a bunch of VLOOKUP references, those don't seem to break from what I can see.  Interesting that only the min/max formulas break? Again, just a theory at this point, I'm not 100% if this is the case. I may have to remove the min/max formulas but that would require a lot of rework, so I'd prefer to just deal with the root problem if I can.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

-Struggling on a Friday

Comment: Is the spreadsheet large?

Comment: Well, there are ~20 feeder sheets, but each sheet is only receiving on average a 4x4 export of data. So it's actually quite small in terms of the number of cells that hold data.  But I suppose it could be that the number of total connections is problematic

Comment: Maybe in order to find out whether the problem is in the min/max formulas or not, you can replace them? For example, on =SORTN(B3:B,1,0,1,FALSE) for MAX() and =SORTN(B3:B,1,0,1,TRUE) for MIN().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried replacing the min/max formulas but ended up encountering the same issue.

At this point I think I'll go a different route, instead of having so many different feeder sheets I can aggregate the data into one redshift reporting table and pipe everything into one landing spot. Hopefully that works better!